# Algorithm behind PhotoPaint's "Subtract" overlay mode?

Tags: image, image-processing

In Corel PhotoPaint, when you overlay two images using the "Subtract" mode instead of "Normal", you will get more saturated, "neater" colors in the darker areas from the top image. Does anyone know what the algorithm behind this overlaying method is? For instance, I'm looking into emulating it in Objective-C as well as PHP.

For comparison, I created an overlay image of a blurred black center circle which in the top, uses the Normal overlaying mode, and in the bottom, uses the Subtract mode. The normal mode will cause the resulting darker area to look much more gray.

[image: Normal]
Normal

[image: Subtract] Subtract

Exporting this CPT file to PSD and opening in Photoshop, the Subtract mode is not available and is lost, so I'm not even sure what it's called in Photoshop.

Thanks for any help! (Original photo CC-licensed by [iPyo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ipyo/4948872706/).)

Answer (score 1):

When combining two images you will have varying options to do so. The general algorithm for such a combination is

```
for each pixel in resultImage
   resultImage[pixel] = sourceA[pixel] OP sourceB[pixel]
```

Well and then you choose OP. In your questions case thats a '-' (subtraction). 
But it can be also +,*,/, MOD, DIV etc.

Usually you will also want to perform some kind of range checking so the pixel intensities of your result image won't over- or underflow. But well then you also might want to do such a thing intentionally.